# creating check box in dropdown menu

Tags: php, javascript, html

this is my select dropdown array ,how can i have check box in front of each option ,and limit user to select maximum 3 option using javascript .

```
<select  onclick="document.getElementById('cand_qual4').style.display='none'; " name="oca2[]" id="oca2"  multiple="multiple">
  <?php
 $odrop = array('B ','M C','D','A','L','k','P','I','OTHER');
 foreach ($odrop as $odrop1)
 {
     echo '<option value="' . $odrop1 . '"' . (isset($_POST['oca2']) && $_POST['oca2'] == $odrop1 ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $odrop1 . '</option>';
  } 
 ?>         
</select>
```

Comment: This has got nothing to do with php

Answer (score 1):

You can't place `<input type="checkbox" />` within `<select />` elements; you'd have to write some javascript to simulate this functionality.

Comment: can u explain script for this,or some reference

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example plugin with which you could achieve that: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/

It offers multiselect just as you described via checkboxes.

(Side note: Took me only 2 minutes to google it. Google is your friend ;)